# Getting the original variable name for an LLVM Value

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, debug-symbols, llvm-ir

The operands for an [`llvm::User`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1User.html) (e.g. instruction) are [`llvm::Value`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html)s.

After the *mem2reg* pass, variables are in [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), and their names as corresponding to the original source code are lost.  `Value::getName()` is only set for some things; for most variables, which are intermediaries, its not set.

The *instnamer* pass can be run to give all the variables names like *tmp1* and *tmp2*, but this doesn't capture where they originally come from.  Here's some LLVM IR beside the original C code:

[image]

I am building a simple html page to visualise and debug some optimisations I am working on, and I want to show the SSA variables as **name<sub>ver</sub>** notation, rather than just temporary instnamer names.  Its just to aid my readability.

I am getting my LLVM IR from clang with a commandline such as:

```
 clang -g3 -O1 -emit-llvm -o test.bc -c test.c
```

There are calls to `llvm.dbg.declare` and `llvm.dbg.value` in the IR; how do you turn into the original sourcecode names and SSA version numbers?

So how can I determine the original variable (or named constant name) from an `llvm::Value`?  Debuggers must be able to do this, so how can I?

Comment: Which program did you use to create such a nice code assembly | source comparision?

Comment: @JackL. I quickly wrote it myself.  Its just a javascript canvas.  When someone earns 500 pts giving human-readable names<sub>ver</sub> to the Values, I might even release it hint hint ;)

Comment: @Will Did you end up releasing your comparison tool?  It would be tremendously useful to many people, I suspect.

Comment: @ransford afraid not.  And, sadly, I never did get much nearer going from intermediary name to SSA<sub>num</sub> either.  My project ran into other difficulties such as LLVM not preserving pointers, which I understand has bitten lots of people wanting precise GC and porting to VLIWs etc too :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is part of the debug information that's attached to LLVM IR in the form of metadata. Documentation [is here](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html). An old blog post with some background [is also available](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/extensible-metadata-in-llvm-ir.html).

---

```
$ cat  > z.c
long fact(long arg, long farg, long bart)
{
    long foo = farg + bart;
    return foo * arg;
}

$ clang -emit-llvm -O3 -g -c z.c
$ llvm-dis z.bc -o -
```

Produces this:

```
define i64 @fact(i64 %arg, i64 %farg, i64 %bart) #0 {
entry:
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata !{i64 %arg}, i64 0, metadata !10), !dbg !17
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata !{i64 %farg}, i64 0, metadata !11), !dbg !17
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata !{i64 %bart}, i64 0, metadata !12), !dbg !17
  %add = add nsw i64 %bart, %farg, !dbg !18
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata !{i64 %add}, i64 0, metadata !13), !dbg !18
  %mul = mul nsw i64 %add, %arg, !dbg !19
  ret i64 %mul, !dbg !19
}
```

With `-O0` instead of `-O3`, you won't see `llvm.dbg.value`, but you will see `llvm.dbg.declare`.

Comment: I think theory and practice diverge :(  I've never had any llvm.dbg.value calls emitted by clang.  The documentation I had read before I asked on SO.

Comment: @Will: clang does not emit `llvm.dbg.value`. Optimizations emit them when they place values into registers (instead of the more easily accessible stack slots).

Comment: Well ok, then how do you get mem2reg or whatever to emit them?  And would they be the secret sauce that lets me turn Values into sourcecode names, and if so, how?

Comment: @Will: if you take a non-trivial C function and emit LLVM IR from it with clang -g (debug info enabled), you'll see debug information in it. llvm.dbg.declare links stack values to original C objects. `mem2reg` may then create some llvm.dbg.value intrinsics; not all LLVM-level values have direct mapping to original C objects, of course - some are just temporaries, ABI-related values, C++ related lowering, etc.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty much *exactly* what I've been doing.  I just don't have any llvm.dbg.values in the emitted bc.  I've added more info to my question, and I'm waiting for the bounty period to start in the hope someone actually works out the actual code to go from Value to name/version.

Comment: `clang -O0` generates unoptimized code, which won't have `llvm.dbg.value` because all the locals are on stack. You need to generate optimized code to see `llvm.dbg.value`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46371/discussion-between-will-and-eli-bendersky)

Answer (score 12):

Given a `Value`, getting variable name from it can be done by traversing all the `llvm.dbg.declare` and `llvm.dbg.value` calls in the enclosing function, checking if any refers to that value, and if so, return the `DIVariable` associated with the value by that intrinsic call.

So, the code should look something like (roughly, not tested or even compiled):

```cpp
const Function* findEnclosingFunc(const Value* V) {
  if (const Argument* Arg = dyn_cast<Argument>(V)) {
    return Arg->getParent();
  }
  if (const Instruction* I = dyn_cast<Instruction>(V)) {
    return I->getParent()->getParent();
  }
  return NULL;
}

const MDNode* findVar(const Value* V, const Function* F) {
  for (const_inst_iterator Iter = inst_begin(F), End = inst_end(F); Iter != End; ++Iter) {
    const Instruction* I = &*Iter;
    if (const DbgDeclareInst* DbgDeclare = dyn_cast<DbgDeclareInst>(I)) {
      if (DbgDeclare->getAddress() == V) return DbgDeclare->getVariable();
    } else if (const DbgValueInst* DbgValue = dyn_cast<DbgValueInst>(I)) {
      if (DbgValue->getValue() == V) return DbgValue->getVariable();
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

StringRef getOriginalName(const Value* V) {
  // TODO handle globals as well

  const Function* F = findEnclosingFunc(V);
  if (!F) return V->getName();

  const MDNode* Var = findVar(V, F);
  if (!Var) return "tmp";

  return DIVariable(Var).getName();
}
```

You can see above I was too lazy to add handling of globals, but it's not that big a deal actually - this requires iterating over all the globals listed under the current compile unit debug info (use `M.getNamedMetadata("llvm.dbg.cu")` to get a list of all the compile units in the current module), then checking which matches your variable (via the `getGlobal` method) and returning its name.

**However**, keep in mind the above will only work for values directly associated with original variables. Any value that is a result of any computation will not be properly named this way; and in particular, values that represent field accesses will not be named with the field name. This is doable but requires more involved processing - you'll have to identify the field number from the GEP, then dig into the type debug information for the struct to get back the field name. Debuggers do that, yes, but no debugger operates in LLVM IR land - as far as I know even LLVM's own LLDB works differently, by parsing the DWARF in the object file into Clang types.

Comment: Very nice and very similar to how I've been finding proper names (although I've been making a reverse map of the Function's symbol table to speed things up slightly).  The big problem is in the *however* section, though; almost all variables in IR are temporaries, although as a human you can follow them back and see where they come from.

Comment: It looks like it no longer works (debug values had a major rework shortly after this answer and now they don't return Value * among other things) and I'm not sure what is the correct way to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of Clang some of the other approaches will not work. 
Instead, use the **-fno-discard-value-names** flag for clang. This will make the llvm::Values keep their original names

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, converting the IR into "SSA variables as **VarName<sub>ver</sub>** notation". The following documentation and links helped me.
1)  https://releases.llvm.org/3.4.2/docs/tutorial/LangImpl7.html
2)  [LLVM opt mem2reg has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513801/llvm-opt-mem2reg-has-no-effect)

Hope this helps the community!!!

Comment: Hi, the links were helpful but I was still unable to achieve this. Could you please elaborate on how you managed to get the original variable names? Thanks