# How to track down LLVM verifyFunction error "Expected no forward declarations!"?

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm developing a compiler for a new language of mine in LLVM and have run into an issue while generating debug information.

I have not yet found much documentation on how to actually generate the debug information using the [DIBuilder](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DIBuilder.html) so it is very possible I'm doing something terribly wrong.

I have been mostly looking at the [Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl8.html) example as it is the only one I have found that uses debug information.  I have yet to crack open Clang to look at how they have been using it, but I would love to hear from someone who has.

I have been able to compile and run my language with some more complex examples, but I started back at some basics for adding the debugging support.  Here is the simple script I am trying to compile:

```
double my_main()
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Here is my output from verifyFunction, verifyModule, and dumping the module.

***Edit: note in edits below I point out that the dump is after a call to finalize which correctly removes the temporary.***

```
Failed To Verify Function: my_main error: Expected no forward declarations!
!8 = <temporary!> !{}

Failed To Verify Module: test.str error: Expected no forward declarations!
!8 = <temporary!> !{}

; ModuleID = 'test.str'

define double @my_main() !dbg !6 {
entry:
  br label %block, !dbg !10

block:                                            ; preds = %entry
  ret double 0.000000e+00, !dbg !10
}

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1}
!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!2}

!0 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!1 = !{i32 2, !"Dwarf Version", i32 2}
!2 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C, file: !3, producer: "Test Compiler", isOptimized: false, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: 1, enums: !4, subprograms: !5)
!3 = !DIFile(filename: "test.str", directory: ".")
!4 = !{}
!5 = !{!6}
!6 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "my_main", scope: !3, file: !3, line: 10, type: !7, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 10, isOptimized: false, variables: !4)
!7 = !DISubroutineType(types: !8)
!8 = !{!9}
!9 = !DIBasicType(name: "double", size: 64, align: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_float)
!10 = !DILocation(line: 9, column: 11, scope: !6)
```

Searching for the error message in the LLVM codebase reveals the source in Verifier.cpp:

> ```
> void Verifier::visitMDNode(const MDNode &MD) {
>   // Only visit each node once.  Metadata can be mutually recursive, so this
>   // avoids infinite recursion here, as well as being an optimization.
>   if (!MDNodes.insert(&MD).second)
>     return;
>
>   switch (MD.getMetadataID()) {
>   default:
>     llvm_unreachable("Invalid MDNode subclass");
>   case Metadata::MDTupleKind:
>     break;
> #define HANDLE_SPECIALIZED_MDNODE_LEAF(CLASS)                                  \
>   case Metadata::CLASS##Kind:                                                  \
>     visit##CLASS(cast<CLASS>(MD));                                             \
>     break;
> #include "llvm/IR/Metadata.def"
>   }
>
>   for (unsigned i = 0, e = MD.getNumOperands(); i != e; ++i) {
>     Metadata *Op = MD.getOperand(i);
>     if (!Op)
>       continue;
>     Assert(!isa<LocalAsMetadata>(Op), "Invalid operand for global metadata!",
>            &MD, Op);
>     if (auto *N = dyn_cast<MDNode>(Op)) {
>       visitMDNode(*N);
>       continue;
>     }
>     if (auto *V = dyn_cast<ValueAsMetadata>(Op)) {
>       visitValueAsMetadata(*V, nullptr);
>       continue;
>     }
>   }
>
>   // Check these last, so we diagnose problems in operands first.
>   Assert(!MD.isTemporary(), "Expected no forward declarations!", &MD);
>   Assert(MD.isResolved(), "All nodes should be resolved!", &MD);
> }
> ```

I'm assuming by the assertion that I have some metadata that is still considered "Temporary", but I would like to know how to track down what is creating it.

I'm creating my types much like how the example does:

```
// here dbuilder is a DIBuilder* and alignment is coming from 
// my Module's getDataLayout().getABITypeAlignment(t);
// where t is Type::getDoubleTy(context.getLLVMContext());
// the context object is my own type
dbuilder->createBasicType("double", 64, alignment, dwarf::DW_ATE_float);
```

My debug function creation logic uses this type, among others, in another call from the example:

```
// the argument is of type: SmallVector<Metadata *, 8> returnPlusParams;
dbuilder->createSubroutineType(dbuilder->getOrCreateTypeArray(returnPlusParams));
```

I am also setting line and column numbers on my [IRBuilder](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html) from my AST nodes:

```
_mBuilder->SetCurrentDebugLocation(DebugLoc::get(node->line, node->column, currentDebugScope()));
```

I was also reading the page on [SourceLevelDebugging](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#object-lifetimes-and-scoping), but this doesn't talk about the C++ API to LLVM as much as the debug IR format.

If anyone notices something obvious in my module dump or has any further suggestions I would appreciate it greatly.

---

## Edit: Adding example IR

I did a few more tests and wanted to post the output of a similar function output from Clang with the following command:

```
clang -cc1 hello_llvm.c -emit-llvm
```

***Edit: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410675/getting-the-original-variable-name-for-an-llvm-value) post to add debug info to the output.***

This code:

```
double main() {
  return 0.0;
}
```

Compiles to this:

```
; ModuleID = 'hello_llvm.c'
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0"

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define double @main() #0 {
entry:
  ret double 0.000000e+00
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-features"="+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 80803f026ba7160f7cfa122c7ef829ab42abc3bf) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 1bb03c5884405c428c3ab54631c0528b6cedeb54)"}
```

It gives the obvious warn to change return type of `main` to int.  I produced an int version as well which produces an alloca:

```
; ModuleID = 'hello_llvm.c'
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0"

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-features"="+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 80803f026ba7160f7cfa122c7ef829ab42abc3bf) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 1bb03c5884405c428c3ab54631c0528b6cedeb54)"}
```

***NOTE:*** In my example `double` was chosen as an arbitrary return type, but `int` also fails.  In some of my initial tests I actually wrap my_main with a proper `main` with argv/argc and was able to compile and run from the terminal.

---

## Edit 2: 'finalize'

I didn't see anything too obvious in the previous IR so I decided to run verifyModule after the module `finalize` call. This was successful and reflected in the IR dump we see above.

I then decided to dump the module prior to finalize.  This time you can see the temp it was complaining about.

```
Failed To Verify Module: test.str error: Expected no forward declarations!
!8 = <temporary!> !{}

; ModuleID = 'test.str'

define i32 @my_main() !dbg !4 {
entry:
  br label %block, !dbg !9

block:                                            ; preds = %entry
  ret i32 0, !dbg !9
}

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1}
!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!2}

!0 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!1 = !{i32 2, !"Dwarf Version", i32 2}
!2 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C, file: !3, producer: "Test Compiler", isOptimized: false, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: 1)
!3 = !DIFile(filename: "test.str", directory: ".")
!4 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "my_main", scope: !3, file: !3, line: 10, type: !5, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 10, isOptimized: false, variables: !8)
!5 = !DISubroutineType(types: !6)
!6 = !{!7}
!7 = !DIBasicType(name: "int32", size: 32, align: 4, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!8 = <temporary!> !{}
!9 = !DILocation(line: 9, column: 11, scope: !4)
```

So I suppose the question is...

Is there something that must be done prior to verify to clean up this temporary? or am I just creating the type incorrectly?  What operations implicitly create temporaries?

Comment: I got the same issue when learning the Kaleidoscope example. @Juicebox's answer is right, but incomplete. If we are generating a function, calling `dbuilder->finalize()` is not convenient. We could call `DBuilder->finalizeSubprogram` (before calling `verifyFunction`) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got around to looking into Clang and noticed that they do not appear to utilize `verifyFunction` at all and `verifyModule` is optionally added as a pass.

```
CODEGENOPT(VerifyModule      , 1, 1) ///< Control whether the module should be run
                                     ///< through the LLVM Verifier.
```

It would appear from what I can see that my issues may not even be valid as it passes `verifyModule` in the end.  I'm opting for the "do as Clang does" here for now.

I'm still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue by using IRBuilder and DIBuilder. The problem on my side was that I was calling `llvm::ExecutionEngine::getFunctionAddress` (which triggers code generation) before finalizing the DIBuilder (`llvm::DIBuilder::finalize()`). 
So ensure you are calling `dbuilder->finalize()` before any code generation of your llvm::Module (in fact before the verify module is invoked).

Answer (score 3):

I am using the LLVM C-API and had the same problem.

It was solved by moving **LLVMDIBuilderFinalize** so it is executed earlier then any of **LLVMVerifyModule** and the optimization passes.