# LLVM pass doesn't perform single static assignment

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, ssa

I'm using the prebuilt LLVM 6.0, when I perform llvm pass `-mem2reg` to generate SSA, the IR code remains as is without being changed. But when I use the prebuilt LLVM 3.8 to do the same thing, the llvm pass works. However, I need to use LLVM 6.0 because I'm using other tools that leverage this LLVM version.

To give a concrete example:
Here is the c code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int total_lines = 0;
    int total_chars = 0;

    int count_chars = 0;
    int count_lines = 0;

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Please specify count line and chars\n");
    } else if (argc ==2){
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-c")){
            count_chars = 1;
        }else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-l")){
            count_lines = 1;
        }
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, 1024,stdin)){
        if (count_chars)
            total_chars += sizeof(buffer);
        if (count_lines)
            total_lines += lineCount();
    }
    if (count_chars)
        printf("Count chars is:: %d\n", total_chars);
    if (count_lines)
        printf("Count Lines is:: %d\n", total_lines);
    return 0;
}
```

I run the LLVM pass to generate the SSA and then generate the human readable IR code using the following commands:

```
LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/clang -c -emit-llvm example.c
LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/llvm-dis example.bc -o h1.ll

//SSA LLVM pass 
LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/opt -mem2reg example.bc -o example_SSA.bc
LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/llvm-dis example_SSA.bc -o h2.ll

diff h1 h2 //I receive the following

< ; ModuleID = 'example.bc'
---
> ; ModuleID = 'example_SSA.bc'
```

While when I do the same previous steps but using prebuilt LLVM 3.8, and `diff h1 h2` I get many differences including the following

```
< ; <label>:50                                      ; preds = %29
<   %51 = load i32, i32* %count_chars, align 4
<   %52 = icmp ne i32 %51, 0
<   br i1 %52, label %53, label %56
< 
< ; <label>:53                                      ; preds = %50
<   %54 = load i32, i32* %total_chars, align 4
<   %55 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([21 x i8], [21 x i8]* @.str.4, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %54)
<   br label %56
< 
< ; <label>:56                                      ; preds = %53, %50
<   %57 = load i32, i32* %count_lines, align 4
<   %58 = icmp ne i32 %57, 0
<   br i1 %58, label %59, label %62
< 
< ; <label>:59                                      ; preds = %56
<   %60 = load i32, i32* %total_lines, align 4
<   %61 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([21 x i8], [21 x i8]* @.str.5, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %60)
<   br label %62
---
> ; <label>:22                                      ; preds = %38, %21
>   %total_lines.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %21 ], [ %total_lines.1, %38 ]
>   %total_chars.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %21 ], [ %total_chars.1, %38 ]
>   %23 = getelementptr inbounds [1024 x i8], [1024 x i8]* %buffer, i32 0, i32 0
>   %24 = load %struct._IO_FILE*, %struct._IO_FILE** @stdin, align 8
>   %25 = call i8* @fgets(i8* %23, i32 1024, %struct._IO_FILE* %24)
>   %26 = icmp ne i8* %25, null
>   br i1 %26, label %27, label %39
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example that illustrates what you mean. Also please provide the generated IR for both solutions. For instance a simple C main-function that does some assignment based on input arguments

Comment: I added more explanation

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution it's based on this answer [LLVM opt mem2reg has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513801/llvm-opt-mem2reg-has-no-effect)

The new version of LLVM annotates the bitcode generated by `clang` to prevent additional optimizations later on. So I just had to add these flags `-Xclang -disable-O0-optnone` to the clang command

`LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/clang -c -emit-llvm example.c`

To

`LLVM_6.0_bin/bin/clang -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -c -emit-llvm example.c`