# LLVM retrieve name of AllocaInst

Tags: c++, cuda, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to retrieve the name of the pointer passed to a [`cudaMalloc`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) call.

```
CallInst *CUMallocCI = ... ; // CI of cudaMalloc call
Value *Ptr = CUMallocCI->getOperand(0);
if (AllocaInst *AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(Ptr) != nullptr) {
  errs() << AI->getName() << "\n";
}
```

The above however just prints an empty line. Is is possible to get the pointer name out of this alloca?

This is the relevant IR:

```
%28 = alloca i8*, align 8
...
...
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i8** %28, metadata !926, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !927
%257 = call i32 @cudaMalloc(i8** %28, i64 1), !dbg !928
...
...
!926 = !DILocalVariable(name: "d_over", scope: !677, file: !3, line: 191, type: !22)
!927 = !DILocation(line: 191, column: 10, scope: !677)
```

Comment: The name you want is down as $28, which is an automatically generated name when an instruction has none. Is that $28 actually what you want?

Comment: @amt I am actually looking for the pointer name in the source code. Or at least the line where the pointer is declared. Also, i am not getting the %28 either.

Comment: Not getting the %28 might be because it's automatically generated; I don't know when this automatic fallback happens. The name you want is somewhere in the debug metadata, if it's anywhere at all, which seems uncertain. Instruction::getDebugLoc() gives you the file/line part of the debug metadata, which seems to be generated by most frontends even if detailed information is not.

Comment: Is it just typo in this question defining 'Ptr' but casting 'Pts'. Also consider that getName returns StringRef and it might need to use it's 'str()' function to get std::string. If nothing works then best solution is to use what @arnt suggests in previous comment.

Comment: As far as i can tell the DebugLoc is not going to give me the name of pointer. At least not straightforwardly. I imagine i'd have to use clang libTooling or something to achieve that. In any case i have found a solution, which i will provide as an answer

Comment: @Arsen It was a typo yes. Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410675/getting-the-original-variable-name-for-an-llvm-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question. It turns out that there is an `llvm.dbg.declare` call (DbgDeclareInst) corresponding to the alloca but it may appear anywhere in the caller function's basic blocks. Probably it comes after the first use of this Alloca value? Not sure. In any case, my solution is to search for `DbgDeclareInst` instructions, check if it is for an `AllocaInst` and if so compare that alloca with the alloca of interest and if equal get the variable name. Something like this:

```cpp
CallInst *CUMallocCI = ... ; // CI of cudaMalloc call
Value *Ptr = CUMallocCI->getOperand(0);
if (AllocaInst *AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(Ptr) != nullptr) {
  if ( !AI->hasName() ) {
    // Function this AllocaInst belongs
    Function *Caller = AI->getParent()->getParent();
    // Search for llvm.dbg.declare
    for ( BasicBlock& BB : *Caller) 
      for (Instruction &I : BB) {
        if ( DbgDeclareInst *dbg = dyn_cast<DbgDeclareInst>(&I))
          // found. is it for an AllocaInst?
          if ( AllocaInst *dbgAI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(dbg->getAddress()))
            // is it for our AllocaInst?
            if (dbgAI == AI)
              if (DILocalVariable *varMD = dbg->getVariable()) // probably not needed?
                errs() << varMD->getName() << "\n";
  } else {
    errs() << AI->getName() << "\n";
  }
}
```